# Paging is not working in GridView while appending values using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Here i have a gridview and i append the retrieved data to it using jquery. I want to use paging in the gridview. But it is not working. I dont know why.. because it works perfectly fine when i use the same method in other applications that binds the grid normally without jquery. Please review my code and tell me what is wrong

this is my grid,

```
<form runat="server">
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" GridLines="None" CellSpacing="10" >

   </asp:GridView>
```

this is my jquery code that appends value(bind) to the grid,

```
$("#search-user")
       .button()
       .click(function () {
           $.ajax({
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               url: "MyHandler.ashx",
               data: {
                   'user': "" + $("#txtsearch").val(),
                   'method': 'search'
               },
               dataType: "json",
               success: updateGrid,
               error: function (result) { alert("Error- Inside user Searching "); }
                });
       });

function updateGrid(data) {
        var i = 0;
        var content;
        $("#GridView1").html('');  // clearing the old data in grid
        $("#GridView1").append("<tr><th>" + "Name" + "</th><th>" + "Gender" + "</th><th>" + "Date of Birth" + "</th><th>" + "Role" + "</th><th>" + "Password" + "</th><th>" + "Email" + "</th></tr>"); 


 while (data[i] != null)
        {  // appending the retrieved data to grid
            $("#GridView1").append("<tr><td>" + data[i].name + "</td><td>" + data[i].gender + "</td><td>" + data[i].dob + "</td><td>" + data[i].role + "</td><td>" + data[i].password + "</td><td>" + data[i].email + "</td></tr>");
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try jqgrids instead of asp grids.

Comment: refer this link  http://sivanandareddyg.blogspot.in/2012/05/paging-in-aspnet-using-jtemplate-jquery.html